# Python: How to overlay histograms using Plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, plotly, histogram

I have two sets of data in separate lists. Each list element has a value from 0:100, and elements repeat.

For example:
`first_data = [10,20,40,100,...,100,10,50]`
`second_data = [20,50,50,10,...,70,10,100]`

I can plot one of these in a histogram using:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
.
.
.

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(histfunc='count', x=first_data))
fig.show()
```

By setting `histfunc` to `'count'`, my histogram consists of an x-axis from 0 to 100 and bars for the number of repeated elements in `first_data`.

My question is: How can I *overlay* the second set of data over the same axis using the same "count" histogram?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One method to do this is by simply adding another trace, you were nearly there!  The dataset used to create these examples, can be found in the last section of this post.

**Note:**
The following code uses the 'lower-level' plotly API, as (personally) I feel it's more transparent and enables the user to see what is being plotted, and why; rather than relying on the convenience modules of `graph_objects` and `express`.

#### Option 1 - Overlaid Bars:

```
from plotly.offline import plot

layout = {}
traces = []

traces.append({'x': data1, 'name': 'D1', 'opacity': 1.0})
traces.append({'x': data2, 'name': 'D2', 'opacity': 0.5})

# For each trace, add elements which are common to both.
for t in traces:
    t.update({'type': 'histogram',
              'histfunc': 'count',
              'nbinsx': 50})

layout['barmode'] = 'overlay'

plot({'data': traces, 'layout': layout})
```

#### Output 1:

[image]

#### Option 2 - Curve Plot:

Another option is to plot the curve (Gaussian KDE) of the distribution, as shown here. It's worth noting that this method plots the *probability density*, rather than the counts.

```
X1, Y1 = calc_curve(data1)
X2, Y2 = calc_curve(data2)

traces = []
traces.append({'x': X1, 'y': Y1, 'name': 'D1'})
traces.append({'x': X2, 'y': Y2, 'name': 'D2'})

plot({'data': traces})
```

#### Output 2:

[image]

Associated `calc_curve()` function:

```
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

def calc_curve(data):
    """Calculate probability density."""
    min_, max_ = data.min(), data.max()
    X = [min_ + i * ((max_ - min_) / 500) for i in range(501)]
    Y = gaussian_kde(data).evaluate(X)
    return(X, Y)
```

#### Option 3 - Plot Bars and Curves:

Or, you can always combine the two methods together, using the probability density on the yaxis.

```
layout = {}
traces = []

traces.append({'x': data1, 'name': 'D1', 'opacity': 1.0})
traces.append({'x': data2, 'name': 'D2', 'opacity': 0.5})

for t in traces:
    t.update({'type': 'histogram',
              'histnorm': 'probability density',
              'nbinsx': 50})

traces.append({'x': X1, 'y': Y1, 'name': 'D1'})
traces.append({'x': X2, 'y': Y2, 'name': 'D2'})

layout['barmode'] = 'overlay'

plot({'data': traces, 'layout': layout})
```

#### Output 3:

[image]

#### Dataset:

Here is the bit of code used to simulate your dataset of [0,100] values, and to create these examples:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

mms = MinMaxScaler((0, 100))
np.random.seed(4)
data1 = mms.fit_transform(np.random.randn(10000).reshape(-1, 1)).ravel()
data2 = mms.fit_transform(np.random.randn(10000).reshape(-1, 1)).ravel()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: My pleasure, hope it helps.  It was a fun question, thanks for the brain exercise.

Comment: I do have a follow up question regarding your calc_curve method. I replaced data1 and data2 in your code for my data variables respectively and the first compile resulted in an error: list object has no attribute .min() and .max(). Therefore I tried converting my data variables to np.array(data) and tried again. This time it's complaining: TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'. From what I can see, min and max are still the cause of the issue.

Comment: It *appears* that one of the min / max values being used is `None`; although I don’t see how this can be the case.  I’d suggest posting a new question with fully reproducible code (please), and tag me in a comment on the question.  I’ll have a look for you tomorrow.

Comment: It appears an element in my data set was a Nonetype. I apologize for the confusion, I fixed it. Thanks again!